# Installing tweepy on Python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to install tweepy on Python 3 within the anaconda prompt `pip install tweepy` however is not working. Does Python 3 support tweepy?

Comment: What is the error message returned when you attempt to pip install? `Python 2.6 and 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 & 3.6 are supported.`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install with Anaconda try the conda install command instead of pip install:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tweepy
```

Ref: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tweepy